# Rxjava lambda expressions

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm currently learning about lambda expressions and have a question regarding RxJava. I thought that lambda expressions can be used so you don't have to create anonymous class and they can only be used if the interface has a single abstract method. Now according to http://reactivex.io/ documentation on observer, it's an interface. Then how is it possible to achieve two lambda expressions within a single interface such as this?

```
 Observable.<User>create(subscriber -> {

    User updatedUser = userService.updateuser(usermapper.userdtotoentity(user));
    subscriber.onNext(updatedUser);

}).subscribe(

     user -> {
       if (user != null) {
          response.resume(user);
      } else {
        response.resume(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build());
      }
    }, 

     error -> {
        logger.debug("User with email_id:" + email_id + " is not present");
        response.resume(error);
     }
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Observable.subscribe` method you are using accepts two parameters, both of which are of a functional interface type. Therefore you can pass a lambda expression as a value for both.

If you feel it will make the code clearer, you can extract the parameters you're passing to local variables:

```
Action1 onNext = user -> { .... };

Action1 onError = error -> { .... };

Observable.<User>create(subscriber -> {....}).subscribe(onNext, onError);
```